# Preventing Jquery QueryBuilder from refresh after 'getRules' called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am using Jquery Query Builder inside HTML form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ......
    ......   
    var filter_json2 = <%=jsonArray%>;
    console.log(<%=jsonArray.toString()%>);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#rule_div').queryBuilder({
            plugins:['bt-tooltip-errors'],
            filters:filter_json2
        });

        $('#btn_reset').on('click', function () {
            $('#rule_div').queryBuilder('reset');
        });

        $('#btn_set').on('click', function () {
            $('#rule_div').queryBuilder('setRules', rules_basic);
        });

        $('#btn_get').on('click', function () {
            var result = $('#rule_div').queryBuilder('getRules');
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                $("#jsonRule").val(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                console.log(result);
            }
        });

    });

    ......
    ......
</script>


    ......
    ......
    ......
    ......

<form action="/jspfile.do" method="post">
    ......
    ......
    other fields in form
    ......
    ......

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div id="rule_div">
            <button class="btn_set" id="btn_set">Set Rules</button>
            <button class="btn_get" id="btn_get">Get Rules</button>
            <button class="btn_reset" id="btn_reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="jsonRule" name="jsonRule" value="">
    </td>
</tr>


</form>
```

when I select something from Query Builder and hit get rules button I am getting json rules but page is getting refreshed and whatever I have selected is getting erased..

This is not the case with demo I am referring [https://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html]

Can anyone please suggest me , How can I prevent selected data from query builder from erasing after refresh?

Comment: use preventDefault

Comment: @Vishwa ,Tried that already, using preventDefault will also block getRules from calling

Comment: how did you tried it?

Comment: `$('#btn_get').on('click', function (event) {
            result = $('#rule_div').queryBuilder('getRules');
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
                $("#jsonRule").val(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });`

Comment: try using it like this, 

$('#btn_get').on('click', function (event) { 
 result = $('#rule_div').queryBuilder('getRules'); 

event.preventDefault(); 

 if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) { 
  alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); 
  $("#jsonRule").val(); 
  $("#jsonRule").val(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); 

 } 
});

Comment: Now this line is not working
$("#jsonRule").val(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
But getting alert

Comment: try moving preventdefault inside if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {

Comment: Still not as expected ,
getting alert but 
  $("#jsonRule").val(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); 
this line is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a form, and any untyped button in a form is a submit button.

if you add `type="button"` to your buttons it should stop them from submitting your form.

Another solution is indeed to always call preventDefault

```
   $('#btn_get').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // custom action here
    });
```